# How to forcefully break the execution of a method

Tags: c++, c, exception, exit, break

I have a method:

```
void doSomethingMain(char* s)
{
   doSomethingElse(s);
   doMoreStuff(s);
}
```

where the method `doSomethingElse()` is like:

```
void doSomethingElse(char* s)
{
   anotherMethod(s);
   moreStuff(s);
}
```

where `anotherMethod()` and `moreStuff()` call other methods, which on their turn might either go back to `doSomethingElse()` or `moreStuff()` or other methods... in a very recursive manner, but none of them calls the main `doSomethingMain()` method. This is a finite recursion, it will end when the `s` is successfully consumed. The methods are void, we cannot change that without a huge effort.

All these methods are consuming the parameter `s` and they are checking for errors in `s`. What I want to happen is the following: when one of the methods somewhere down the call stack encounters an error in its input parameter (`s`) the I want immediately abort the execution of the function that found the error, and jump back to the `doMoreStuff()` in the `doSomethingMain()`.

Obviously, one of the immediate solutions from a `C++` approach is a `throw` and a `catch()` pair, and from a `C` approach is a `setjmp` and `longjmp` pair... However our unit testing framework does not like the `throw` ... `catch` pairs (it interprets them as errors) and I would like to avoid the `longjmp` approach, so here is the question:

What other alternatives do we have in order to interrupt the execution flow of the application in a method and to continue at a specific location (the next statement after the method)?

Comment: This is exactly what `longjmp()` is for, sorry. However, you could in theory make all your functions return an error code, then all calls to these functions should be checked for a return code, and when an error is encountered, any function should return immediately (with the same error code). Thus, one error will result in an immediate  return to the first caller (through all other frames on the call stack).

Comment: The true answer depends on the language you want to use. Is it now C or C++?

Comment: @H2CO3: Nice. Dare making it an answer! ;-)

Comment: I daresay throwing is _exactly_ the right solution for what you want (though I think what you want may be wrong, `assert` may be more applicable if a deeply nested recursive function finds that its input params are wrong -- but that's debatable). Anyway, this is the kind of "error, happens rarely" case where exceptions excel. Properly calls destructors, clear code, and works without crashing. Why would a test framework not like exceptions? If you do catch and don't rethrow, the test framework never gets to see them.

Answer (score 1):

You could change methods to return `bool`. If the parsing is successful, at the end of the recursion, return `true` which will be passed to the caller function. If parsing at any point proves to be not successful, return `false`, and in the caller function test return value of the entire recursion.

> However our unit testing framework does not like the throw ... catch pairs (it interprets them as errors, and no more tests are executed after them)

Change your testing unit framework.

Comment: Then you don't have any problems :)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about `throw`ing at the point of the error.

Comment: Yes, me too, but the google test framework swallows the throw :( Prints a message like: `unknown file: Failure
Unknown C++ exception thrown in the test body.`

Answer (score 1):

Return an error code, which is checked. You can, for example, return `false` (see `<stdbool.h>` in C) on error, and `true` on success. If a function returns `false, then return (possible with`false` as well).

Using `setjmp`/`longjmp` is not something I would recommend, even for cases like this.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is already an API (based on these silly void methods) which is used for quite a time by the customers of the company and they would be very unhappy if the API would change... :(

Answer (score 1):

This is *exactly* what `longjmp()` is for, sorry. However, you could in theory make all your functions return an error code, then **all calls to these functions should be checked** for a return code. When an error is encountered, any calling function should **return immediately** (with the same error code). Thus, one error will result in an immediate return to the first caller (through all other frames on the call stack).

Comment: When I tried the `longjmp` the application got a SIGSEGV ... possibly because it's (more or less) C++? Like: C++ methods call C methods (with a pointer to a C++ object... which on their turn call back to another object).

Comment: @fritzone I don't think that's a problem. I suspect you were using `longjmp()` incorrectly (it's easy to use incorrectly...)

Comment: `longjmp` doesn't play well with C++. Destructors don't get called when you call it.

Comment: @Sean That's true, but why would a destructor that is not called segfault? At best it leaks memory, no?

Comment: I do not like memory leaks... the app is supposed to run for a long time, without restarting it :(

Comment: @fritzone If you want to avoid `longjmp()` completely, then you don't have any other option than the "long but normal return chain" approach, I believe.

Comment: @H2CO3 I am afraid of that too :(

Comment: IF you know how much memory you need further down the line you could pre-allocate it at the top and then let the functions below use from that pool. In case you need to longjmp out you can free the pool or reuse.

Answer (score 1):

> However our unit testing framework does not like the throw ... catch
>   pairs (it interprets them as errors, and no more tests are executed
>   after them)

What about this:

```
try
{
  doMoreStuff(s);
}
catch (...)
{
  // hmmm I won't rethrow because my unit testing framework doesn't like it
}
```

A valid reason for not using exceptions would be, if for some reason, they were disabled (`-fno-exceptions`).

Answer (score 0):

Best way without jumps or gotos is to check returns and do a do while loop:

```
    void myFunc(char *s) {

      bool doneAll = false;
      int res = 0;

      do {
        res = doSomething(s);
        if(!res) break;
        res = doSomethingElse(s);
        if(!res) {
          break;
        } else { 
          doneAll = true;
        }
      while (false); // no really a loop, a smart way of using breaks
      // you know can access doneAll to check if everything is done

      // Any cleanup here as well
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach - use a global error flag.

```
static int found_error = 0;

void anyFunction(char *s) {
    if (found_error) return;

    if (something_failed) {
        found_error = 1;
        return;
    }
}
```

Now, after an error has been detected, some functions will still be called, but will do nothing.